# Making asyncio gather wait until all tasks are done

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have functions that are supposed to run in paraller and gather data for a second, and then return the data once the time has passed.

Problem is, one task (to my understanding) finishes before the other, causing `results` to be empty on that result. Below code for example:

```py
import asyncio
import time

async def task(id, end_time):
    print('Started task ', id)
    results = []
    while time.time() < end_time:
        results.append(1)
    return results


async def main():
    while True:
        end_time = time.time() + 1
        results = await asyncio.gather(*[task(i,end_time) for i in range(2)])
        print(len(results[0]), len(results[1]))
try:
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
finally:
    loop.close()
```

returns

```
Started task  0
Started task  1
5580452 0
```

Where am I going wrong? I know I should somehow make it wait for all tasks to be finished before doing things with the results, but don't really know how to achieve this, after a while of fiddling around with different things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to `gather` them differently. The way you use `asyncio` is ok.

In your `task` coroutine remove the `while` and just append to `results` once. You will see that both tasks will return their outputs.

The problem is that when you do `while time.time()` you lock it, as it's not asynchronous. So it runs the `while` loop until the `end_time` condition is met.

Then the second one starts, since the `task` coro never allowed anything else to be executed in the meantime. As both were using the same `end_time`, the second coro will never append.

If you want to run the `while` loop asynchronously, you need to create additional asynchronous logic for it and `await` it in your `task` function.

EDIT:
For example, if you just want put it back to the event loop and allow something else to be executed, simply put `await asyncio.sleep(0.1)` in your while loop.

Example:

```
async def task(id, end_time):
    print('Started task ', id)
    results = []
    while time.time() < end_time:
        results.append(1)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.000000001)
    return results
```

Room for improvement:

- `asyncio.run(main()` takes care of creating event loop
- appending to list is an expensive operation, try `+= 1` in loop, so your `results` would be `0` at the beginning, then print results, not their len

Comment: Ah, great, thanks. I thought I was on the right track.

One more question, though.

This is supposed to be part of a program that reads sensors of an IoT-device. The amount of data that comes from each sensor varies, so one sensor can provide 10,000 readings per second and one only 2,000, for example.

Right now all sensors provide about an equal amount of stuff when I run this program. Why is this and is there any way around this? I'm more than happy with the current amount of data that I get, but hypothetically if I would ever need this.

Comment: @user3553653 hey, no problem. Not sure I follow you, but the way you `await` in 'inner coroutines' might be tricky sometimes. Try not to use `await asyncio.sleep`, even if it works for you, as you don't really need to sleep. Create your logic around executing small tasks, literally. And hand it back to the loop once the smallest piece is done. If all tasks sleep for a second at more or less the same time, then nothing happens for a second. You want tasks to be consumed one after another. Asyncio is a different mindset. Good luck!

Comment: Ah yes, silly question now that I think about it. Obviously I should just let it "pump data" and grab it from whatever period I want and for whatever resolution. Thanks.

Comment: `await asyncio.sleep(0)` is enough to yield to the event loop.